# cannot find the symbol error in inheritance program in java

Tags: java, inheritance

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
class First 
{
    public int No;
    public String Name; 
    void getDetails() throws IOException
    {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    No = sc.nextInt();
    Name = sc.nextLine();
    }   
    void showDetails() throws IOException
    {
    System.out.println("The No and Name entered is: " +No  +"\t" +Name);
    }
}

class Second extends First
{
    public double Salary;   
    public void showSalary() throws IOException
    {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader (System.in) );
    Salary = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine() );
    System.out.println(" The salary for no:" +No +"is" +Salary);
    }
}

class Demo_Inheritance 
{
    public static void main(String s[]) throws IOException
    {
     Second sd = new Second();
     sd.getDetails();
     sd.showDetails();
     sd.showSalary();
    First fs = new First();
    fs.getDetails();
    fs.showDetails();
    fs.showSalary(); }
}
```

When i execute this coding, im getting the error in the last line as " fs.showSalary() "-> cannot find the symbol ". (dot)"

Comment: Your 'First' class does not have a `showSalary()` function...

Answer (score 2):

The method `showSalary` is not defined in `First`. You need to either add the method or use an instance of `Second` to use the method

Answer (score 2):

Compiler always resolve the method invocation or field access, based on the declared type of the reference on which it is accessed.

Since declared type of `fs` is `First`, compiler will look for the method declaration of `showSalary()` in `First` class, but it can't find one. And hence it gives the compiler error.